# Organize application SASS files using Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass, themes

I'm starting to work on a large application styling files. As Bootstrap 4 offers SASS files, I decided to follow that path.

I have built the following files structure:

- **theme.scss**: general definitios for the theme like colors and fonts. Today there is just one but there could be more in the future.
- **global.scss**: includes Bootstrap, some Bootstrap overrides and application componentes -i.e. a field with its label as part of the top border.
- **site.scss**: general application styles.
- additional **page-specific** SCSS files. I.e.: login.scss.

The problem I'm having is that `global.scss` -the one that imports Bootstrap- is then imported by `site.scss` as well as other files like page-specific SCSS files. So, Bootstrap styles end up in more than one compiled CSS. Compiled CSS files are what the application actually references.

I've previously used LESS and I could solve this using `@import (reference) "bootstrap"` instead of just plain `@import "bootstrap"`. With SASS I haven't been able to find any solution to this problem without modifying Bootstrap core files.

Is there any other recommended way to organize the files and avoid this problem? Am I missing something or doing anything wrong?

Here are the files contents (they are large files but I'm posting only enough contents to show the problem I'm having):

**theme.scss**

```
$my-primary-color: #04459a;
```

**global.scss**

```
@import "../theme.scss";
$primary: $my-primary-color;
@import "../../third-party/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
%field{
    // [...]
}
```

**site.scss**

```
@import "global.scss";
div.field {
    @extend %field;
}
// [...]
```

**login.scss** (or many other)

```
@import "global.scss";
// [...]
```

In the application I'm referencing `site.css` and `login.css` (in the loign page, of course) and both of them include Bootstrap styles.

Comment: Why are you importing `global.scss` in `site.scss`? What else is in `site.scss`? Does it reference bootstrap variables?

Comment: I've just edited the question adding part of the code of `site.scss`. `site.scss` as well as specific-page SASS files will use variables and mixins both from Bootstrap and from my own (`theme.scss` and `global.scss`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built something that works for me, not sure if it's the best solution or which drawbacks it has, though.

I took some ideas from this article: [My favored SCSS setup with Bootstrap 4](https://medium.com/@programmiri/my-favored-scss-setup-with-bootstrap-4-547e9ea290f8). Here's what I've built:

- First I created two SASS files for importing Bootstrap (similar to what the article does with `bootstrap/_config.scss` but splitted):

**bootstrap/_sass-componentes.scss**

```
@import "../../terceros/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "../../terceros/bootstrap/scss/_variables";
@import "../../terceros/bootstrap/scss/_mixins";
```

**bootstrap/_config.scss**

```
@import "_sass-componentes.scss";
// Every other bootstrap file I want to include:
@import "../../terceros/bootstrap/scss/_root";
@import "../../terceros/bootstrap/scss/_reboot";
@import "../../terceros/bootstrap/scss/_type";
// [...]
@import "../../terceros/bootstrap/scss/_utilities";
@import "../../terceros/bootstrap/scss/_print";
```

- Then in `global.scss` I changed the `bootstrap.scss` import line to import only `bootstrap/_sass-componentes.scss`
- Finally, in `site.scss` I included `global.scss` (such as it was before) and then full Bootstrap files trough `bootstrap/_config.scss`. **

** After importing `_config.scss` I also import my Bootstrap customizations. For doing them I followed the recomendation of the linked article although they do not apply directly to my own question.